# How can I orient the asp.net dyanmic menu as horizontal

Tags: asp.net, menu

I am developing a web site for engineering purpose. I am using a master page. On the master page I have put ASP.Net menu control, and dynamically changing the static and it's dynamic menus. I need the top static menus are in horizontal look, that we can get directly by setting the orientation property. But while hovering on the static menu, the submenus are vertical. I need the sub menus are also in horizontal look. For ref. you can visit www.airIndia.com or [http://home.airindia.in/SBCMS/WebPages/Home.aspx?CityId=Ind](http://www.airIndia.com).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but several ASP.NET forum posts regarding horizontal submenus referred to [this article](http://blogs.ipona.com/davids/archive/2008/08/19/tab-style-menus.aspx).  It uses a combination of two `<asp:Menu>`s to achieve the effect.

Also, I would look into use [CSS adapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/), but I've also found that people who have tried this before got to the point where they were trying to modify JavaScript as well, and eventually gave up and used third party components.

Perhaps you could even roll your own and use the `<asp:Repeater>` control, binding your SiteMap to it.  There are plenty of CSS-based navigation menus, just search around.  A List Apart is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me little bit. But I am not getting that effect which I want. Thanks